# Send mail with BCC on blackberry programmatically

Tags: asp.net, email, blackberry

I have an application in asp.net with jquery mobile. In this application people can send emails. The href to send the email looks like this: "mailto:someemail@email.com?BCC=somebccemail@email.com". If you run this on a PC you get the email box with an BCC filled in. This is a mobile application that will run on a Blackberry torch. When I run this the blackberry opens an email box with no BCC filled in. The BCC box is not available... When I add the BCC via options of that email the box is blank.

Is there a way to do this on a blackberry?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is neither asp.net nor jquery related. It is to do with how the blackberry handles the mailto: html link.

There is no stated support here:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_link_behaviour_438487_11.jsp

although that may be just the documentation lacking. You are doing everything correct from an html point of view.